Rider not showing project errors for React Native app
Rider would not show any project error as WebStorm would for the whole project so after I make a mistake in a file and open another one, the error would not be shown.
I would like to know if it is possible to show the project errors in Rider as it is in WebStorm for React Native applications.

Is it a Typescript or JavaScript project? In the former case, please ensure the Show project errors option is enabled in TypeScript settings (Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript) and the Typescript language service is on.

It is not possible to see project errors on Rider at this moment. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-56016/Integrate-IDEA-JavaScript-TypeScript-errors-into-Problems-View-Errors-in-Solution

It is not possible to see project errors right now using Rider. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-56016/Integrate-IDEA-JavaScript-TypeScript-errors-into-Problems-View-Errors-in-Solution
Please upvote it so they will pick this up.
